# How does `setup.py sdist` work?

Tags: python, distutils

I'm trying to make a source distribution of my project with `setup.py sdist`. I already have a functioning `setup.py` that I can install with. But when I do the `sdist`, all I get is another `my_project` folder inside my `my_project` folder, a `MANIFEST` file I have no interest in, and a zip file which contains two text files, and not my project.

What am I doing wrong? Where is the documentation on `sdist`?

**Update:**

Here's my `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from distutils.core import setup
import distutils
from general_misc import package_finder

try:
    distutils.dir_util.remove_tree('build', verbose=True)
except:
    pass

my_long_description = \
'''\
GarlicSim is a platform for writing, running and analyzing simulations. It can
handle any kind of simulation: Physics, game theory, epidemic spread,
electronics, etc.
'''

my_packages = package_finder.get_packages('', include_self=True,
                                          recursive=True)

setup(
    name='GarlicSim',
    version='0.1',
    description='A Pythonic framework for working with simulations',
    author='Ram Rachum',
    author_email='cool-rr@cool-rr.com',
    url='http://garlicsim.org',
    packages=my_packages,
    package_dir={'': '..'},
    license= "LGPL 2.1 License",
    long_description = my_long_description,

)

try:
    distutils.dir_util.remove_tree('build', verbose=True)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Are you in your package directory when you run it? Is the source code in the package directory too?

Comment: Michael: Yes and yes. `setup.py` is in the same place where the topmost `__init__.py` is.

Comment: Usually setup.py would be one directory above where a package with `__init__.py` is.

Answer (score 11):

Tarek Ziade explained this, and related software packaging tools, in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20200227202149/https://zetcode.com/articles/packageinpython/) (broken [original link](http://zetcode.com/articles/packageinpython/)) called Writing a Package in Python.

Basically, it creates a simple package by
creating a release tree where everything needed to run the package is copied. This tree is then archived in one or many archived files (often, it just creates one tar ball). The archive is basically a copy of the source tree.

Comment: The article link is broken

Comment: @thanos.a Updated the link to point to an archive.org's snapshot

Answer (score 8):

the "sdist" command is for creating a "source" distribution of a package.   Usually, one would combine this command with the "upload" command to distribute the package through Pypi (for example).